# Django: How to properly display formsets as radio-button group

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to make a form for writing problem and providing choices for the problem. Correct choice for the problem is indicated by the selected radio button. Whether a choice is correct choice for a problem is indicated by boolean field `Choice.is_correct_choice`.

In my templates, I have the following:

```
    {% for form in choice_form %}
    <input type="radio" name="selected_choice_number" value="{{ forloop.counter }}"> {{ form.as_p }}
{% endfor %}
```

choice_form is the formset containing choice.

And, in views.py, I have:

```
        form = request.POST

        selected_choice_number = int(form['selected_choice_number'])

        print(form["selected_choice_number"])

        for counter, form in enumerate(choice_form, start=1):
            choice = form.save(commit=False)
            choice.problem = problem
            choice.is_choice_correct = (selected_choice_number == counter)

            print(choice.choice_text, choice.is_choice_correct)
            choice.save()
```

choice_form formset is instance of formset of following form:

```
class MCQChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Choice
    fields = ['choice_text']
    labels = {
        'choice_text': "",
    }
    widgets = {
        "choice_text": forms.Textarea(),
    }
```

This is working fine but It looks ugly to me, specially the code in templates. How can I improve the code so that radio button logic is coded in Python (form/views) instead of templates?